# Is it possible to package Selenium test cases into a runnable appliction

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, software-packaging

I am creating selenium test to test a web app. I also want to be able to use these test cases as a way for non technical users to automate the first few steps of the process. ~Is this possible?

Comment: What `process`? You mean test pre-conditions or test start? You can create simple GUI so that user can perform actions just clicking buttons or sending parameters to appropriate input fields. Look toward something like `TCL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using testng, generate command to [run XML](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng) from the command line and then copy the same command to .bat or .cmd file. By a click any user can run those tests/suite.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can, Selenium automates browsers, it is not a 'test library' you can use it in any program. Just write java program where you use selenium.

You can also write tests (in JUnit or TestNG or any other test runner) and run tests programmatically.